# How can I get current word's paragraph and delete it?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a word relation application,now I've got a bookmark in a position,how can I get current paragraph and delete it?Thanks.Pieces of code are as below.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Word Application class
/// </summary>
public class WordApplication
{
    object nullobj=Missing.Value;
    _Application app;
    _Document doc;

    public WordApplication()
    {
        app=new ApplicationClass();
        Config config = new Config();
        object file = config.InputFilePath;
        try {
            doc=app.Documents.Open(ref file,ref nullobj,ref nullobj,
                ref nullobj,ref nullobj,ref nullobj,
                ref nullobj,ref nullobj,ref nullobj,
                ref nullobj,ref nullobj,ref nullobj,
                ref nullobj,ref nullobj,ref nullobj,ref nullobj) as _Document;
            doc.Activate();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.Log(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove current paragraph
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bookmark"></param>
    public void RemoveParaghRange(string bookmark)
    {
        foreach (Bookmark bm in doc.Bookmarks) {
            if (bm.Name.Equals(bookmark)) {
                //TODO:That's the point.How can I do it?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point is this:How can I get current paragraph,and then I can remove this paragraph.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: How are your data structured? Is the text just one long string, and your bookmark an index to a poisition in this string? Or is there something more complex going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the current selection to the bookmark with [Bookmark.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb240818%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
bm.Select();
```

Then, you can use the *Selection* object to work with the [paragraphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.paragraphs.aspx) referenced by the bookmark:

```
var paragraphs = app.Selection.Paragraphs;
```

Comment: Thanks,and then,how can I delete this paragraph?

Comment: In VBA, it's `myParagraph.Range.Delete()`, the interop library probably contains a similar method.

Comment: object oBookmark=bookmark;
            doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmark).Select();
            object unit;
            unit = WdUnits.wdParagraph;
            object oExtend;
            oExtend = WdMovementType.wdExtend;
            int start= app.Selection.MoveUp(ref unit, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
            int end=app.Selection.MoveDown(ref unit, ref nullobj, ref oExtend);
            object oStart=start;
            object oEnd=end;
            Range range = doc.Range(ref oStart,ref oEnd);
            unit = WdUnits.wdCharacter;
            range.Delete(ref unit,ref nullobj);

Comment: @WangHongjian: I don't know. If you want to debug it, I suggest you use Word and VBA directly, that should help you find the issue.